# "Date" property exists in Object but returns "undefined"

Tags: node.js, csv, utf-8, stream, ucs2

So I'm using fast-csv to get all the rows from a csv file. The file I'm using is in UTF-16 format and using a ucs2 readStream, I'm getting every record out of the file.

```
_csv.fromStream(stream, {headers: true, delimiter: '\t'})
        .on("record", function(data) {
            count ++;
            console.log(data.Date);
            var dataHash = hash(data);
            if (!dict.hasOwnProperty(dataHash)) {
                dict[dataHash] = 1;
            } else {
                dict[dataHash]++;
            }
        })
```

I'm taking each row and I'm hashing it into a "|" delimited string. However, the date is not ever coming back correction. If I console.log(data), the Date property is definitely there but I cannot access it with data.Date, data["Date"], and data.hasOwnProperty("Date"); doesn't work either. The object looks like:

```
{
    'Date': '07/10/2014',
    '[Value 1]': 'xxx',
    '[Value 2]': 'xxx',
    '[Value 3]': 'xxx',
    '[Value 4]': 'xxx',
}
```

Has anyone seen this before and maybe know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Also, if I perform a for(var x in obj) { console.log(x) } 

Date gets printed...

Answer (score 0):

The problem had to do with either leading or trailing garbage. I was able to use a trim property on the fast-csv parser to fix the issue.